# Android: Supporting multiple screen sizes within the same screen size type

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem I am running into related to supporting multiple screen sizes - a fairly common one I believe. I have searched a lot, but have not found something helpful.

I have my project laid out traditionally, with folders to support the various sizes called `layout`, `layout-small`, `layout-large`, `layout-xlarge`.

So as I have found out, even within each of these size regimes, there screens are not all the same size. For example, my 320x480 screen qualifies for the normal size layout, but so does someone's 480x800. As you can imagine, the content of my app will not fill up the whole screen of a 480x800 device because there is more area. Here are examples of what it looks like:

On 320x480 (what I designed for):

[image]

On 480x800 (notice the extra space at the bottom):

[image]

Now, I have done a lot of research and applied lots of techniques in an effort to make my app look nice on all screen, but I feel like I am missing something fundamental. I have taken all the basic steps to use `dp` instead of `px`, use `RelativeLayout` everywhere, stuff like that. But I need some way for my app to re-size itself to better fit the larger screens. For example, the margins between the various components could increase a little to occupy more of the empty vertical space.

Any advice, or help?  In the worst case, is there a way to design a layout which would fire up specifically for 480x800 screens (because they seem to be most common)? Thanks.

Comment: You need to define how "better fit the larger screens" should look like & what parts of the UI should strech / shrink in a very early stage of your layout. Android will do what you want if you use the layouts etc correctly

Comment: @zapl Thanks, did so. I would like the margins, for example, to increase between the various components so that the empty space is minimized. I don't need it to look the same as 320x480, the 480x800 is longer in a relative sense anyways. I just want to minimize the empty space by adjusting the margins mostly.

Comment: You can for example add empty `View`s between your rows and let them scale with weights or define different margins as configuration dependant [dimensions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd use a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- Your first form line -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- Your second form line -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- Your third form line -->
    </LinearLayout>
        <!-- .... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout will produce [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/232549/linearlayout_sample.PNG) (without colors, of course :) ). The ratio of the lines (colored boxes) is fix, but it's size is dinamically fit to the screen height. The fill_parent and layout_weight do the trick.

If you want to use RelativeLayout, you have to set the whitespaces and heights programatically from JAVA (some explanation [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/))

Comment: Thanks! But hold on, I can't use weights with `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: You can't. As I know, if you want to keep the RelativeLayout (not a bad idea), you have to use a custom ViewGroup. There is an example in the end of my post. You can get the container's height from onMeasure(). getChildNum gives the number of items (lines), so lineheight = containerheight / itemnum. After that, in the onLayout() function you can place every children by its calculated dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

320 : 480 has a different ratio than 480 : 800. So the latter simply has more vertical space in relation to the horizontal space than the former. So there is nothing wrong with your layout.

Comment: Well, ya, but I'd like my layout to adapt a little by fixing the margins between the EditText fields, and increasing their heights a little so that the empty space isn't so prevalent. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to design screens so that you *always* think about how the Views you define behave when the screen's size shrinks or grows. As you saw, screens may be varying greatly even in the same size-category.

In the case of the screen that you showed, you need to give the width of the EditText components by using weights, not exact dp amounts. You can find many articles on how you might do this, [here](http://joseluisugia.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/)'s one for a start.